# Latest version string in Nuget 3.0

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-core

In project.json I would like to add dependency to latest version of nuget package in my feed (I use private ones). The only accepted dependency is like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ncommon": "[0.0,)"
}
```

But it looks stupid :). Is there anyway to write `"latest"` or `""` or `*`

Answer (score 0):

Not getting the latest one is by-design they say, see
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/19/Nuget-Dependencies-and-latest-Versions
and
http://blog.nuget.org/20131216/update-all-experience-explained.html

Also see
http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/05/05/Picking-the-right-dependency-version-adding-packages-from-NuGet.aspx
(some more details on NuGet configuration here: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2014/03/11/NuGet-Configuration-File-inheritance-is-awesome.aspx) on how you could configure a client project to pull in the latest version

can't enforce it from the package side though as you'd like to do - I see last comment at the related discussion is 1 year ago, so probably the've settled to that design by now

Comment: If they support float always by design, why they use asterisk ended versions?

Comment: I know that I can write something like 1.0.0.* but this mean that I cannot upgrade automatically to 2.0.0.*